# Bilinear forms and polarization identity

Tags: functional-analysis, bilinear-form, sesquilinear-forms

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\sigma: H \times H \to \mathbb{C}$ a sesquilinear form (linear in the first variable, anti-linear in the second variable). Then it is well-known that the following polarization identity holds:

$$\sigma(x,y)=\frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=0}^3 i^k \sigma(x+i^k y, x + i^ky)$$

Is there a similar result when $\sigma: H \times H \to \mathbb{C}$ is bilinear (linear in both variables)? I.e. is there a way to express $\sigma(x,y)$ as a linear combination of elements of the form $\sigma(z,z)$?

Comment: The symmetry argument missing in your question. since the polarization formula holds only  if $\sigma(x,y)=\overline{\sigma(y,x)}$.

Comment: @GuyFsone This is not true. See the other comments.

Answer (score 2):

It's even easier:
\begin{align*}
\sigma(x,y) &= \frac{\sigma(x+y,x+y)-\sigma(x,x)-\sigma(y,y)}{2} \\ &=\frac{\sigma(x+y,x+y)-\sigma(x-y,x-y)}{4}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think you are assuming that the form is symmetric.

Comment: So? The polarisation identity for sesquilinear forms assumes conjugate symmetry?

Comment: No, it doesn't actually!

Comment: In fact, without assuming symmetry the situation of reconstructing $\sigma$ from the quadratic form $q(v)=\sigma(v,v)$ is hopeless, as the quantity $\sigma(v,v)$ depends only on the symmetric part of $\sigma$! Could you refer me to your source that says the polarisation identity doesn't assume some sort of symmetry?

Comment: Murphy's "C*-algebras and operator theory" p49.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need any form of symmetry. If the form is positive, symmetry comes even for free.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question.